# Vinegar salt reaction to produce acid; does it matter what type of vinegar I use

Tags: acid-base, home-experiment

I am trying to get get hydrogen chloride gas by using the reaction ***sodium chloride + vinegar = HCl(g) + sodium acetate***, does it matter what type of vinegar I use eg apple cider vinegar, malt vinegar; if it does matter where could i find some pure vinegar at a reasonable price

Comment: No it doesn't matter. The result won't change.

Comment: Since the reaction won't work for any type of vinegar, the type won't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two show stoppers :

1. $\ce{HCl}$ is strong acid, $\ce{CH3COOH}$ is weak acid. The reaction is practically completely shifted toward acetic acid and sodium chloride. Especially if acetic acid is diluted.
2. $\ce{HCl}$ forms azeotrope with water with the maximal boiling point near 20% $\ce{HCl}$. If you heat the mixture, that would boil water and acetic acid with minimal traces of $\ce{HCl} $ that would dissolve back in the condensate.